# Spring Transaction Management for files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, in-memory

I am trying to reset the state of a project using config files. The idea is to delete everything that is in memory and then read the files again. I have several files that contain different configs that end up being objects in memory. Now I want the whole operation to be transactional in the sense that if one read fails then the process stops:

```
public void reset(){
   Object config1 =  helper.readFile1();
   Object config2 = helper.readFile2();
   
   //This is the part that should be transactional
   repository.deleteAll();
   repository.saveConfig1(config1);
   repository.saveConfig2(config2);

}
```

Repository holds some data in memory. Delete cleans up this data. Save adds data to memory.

If saveConfig1 fails then the whole set of operations on memory should be rolled back.

So far I have read about Spring's Platform Transaction Manager:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html

However the different implementations are all tailored for differente database related techonologies, not objects in memory. Is there any way to have transactional behavior when using objects that hold data in memory?

Comment: Why not use an in-memory database, then?

Comment: Hello. Well this is part of larger project and these classes are kind of legacy now. The reset functionality was thought about much later.